# How to retrieve 2D view from linked issue in BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I have issues attached to 2D views of Revit 2022 document and I want to retrieve metadata properties for those views, however I can't figure out how to retrieve the view GUID.

Here is my workflow:

From issue Id I retrieve the issue payload using [GET issues/:id:](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-:id-GET/). Here is a fragment of the payload attributes:

```
"attributes": {
    "created_at": "2022-06-30T02:34:49.796Z",
    "synced_at": "2022-06-30T02:34:49.884Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-21T16:58:03.553Z",
    "close_version": null,
    "closed_at": null,
    "closed_by": null,
    "created_by": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
    "opened_at": "2022-06-30T02:34:49.796Z",
    "opened_by": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
    "updated_by": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
    "starting_version": 1,
    "title": "Revit 2022 Sheet issue",
    "description": null,
    "location_description": null,
    "markup_metadata": null,
    "tags": null,
    "target_urn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:Gkv5194oQLOx8IEPaJUBmA",
    "target_urn_page": null,
    "collection_urn": null,
    "due_date": "2022-06-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "identifier": 215,
    "status": "open",
    "assigned_to": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
    "assigned_to_type": "user",
    "answer": null,
    "answered_at": null,
    "answered_by": null,
    "pushpin_attributes": {
      "type": "TwoDRasterPushpin",
      "location": {
        "x": 19.692577166381,
        "y": 17.61800469485458,
        "z": 0
      },
      "object_id": null,
      "viewer_state": null,
      "created_at": "2022-06-30T02:34:49.938Z",
      "created_by": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
      "created_doc_version": null,
      "external_id": null,
      "attributes_version": 1
    },
    "snapshot_urn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:ng-issues-prod-2df67853-df3f-493c-a09c-d1aee3aa439c/a2e0343e-1072-4bf8-a12e-ed1aa6a8ea64",
    "owner": "YCPJREYYBJSE",
    "issue_type_id": null,
    "issue_type": null,
    "issue_sub_type": null,
    "root_cause_id": "8338ce72-cc83-49d7-90ca-93a3dd3d6ac7",
    "root_cause": "CONSTRUCTABILITY",
    "quality_urns": null,
    "permitted_statuses": [
      ..
    ],
    "permitted_attributes": [
     ...
    ],
    ...
    "sheet_metadata": {
      "is3D": false,
      "sheetGuid": "7a052135-c2ef-4a49-a628-ba9211dc7aae-0005787e",
      "sheetName": "A102 - Unnamed"
    },
```

From `target_urn` I retrieve [the item](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/), then get tip version, then using the version URN I invoke the [GET {urn}/metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/), but only 3D views seem to be returned. I definitely have 2d views in my document and I also don't see the last 2 views (Existing & New construction)

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "metadata",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "name": "{3D}",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "00631597-d254-2fc6-351a-eedbc994fa89"
      },
      {
        "name": "3D View 1",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "e829f661-e982-5fec-b3f2-e87bcd1e1d6e"
      },
      {
        "name": "3D View 2",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "4b44f8df-ff26-2a7b-3703-1d2c4b9970d9"
      },
      {
        "name": "3D View 3",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "9e5f8bac-b41e-f96f-2e2e-08eab35309b8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Existing",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "c87a030e-38d5-af19-6e99-bc734b4e91c2",
        "isMasterView": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New Construction",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "db161bd1-7870-2fee-bcd6-7a8d4606f079",
```

So what am I missing?

[image: 2d views in BIM360]

[image: 3d views in BIM360]

I would also expect to retrieve the field `attributes.sheet_metadata.sheetGuid`(in that case "7a052135-c2ef-4a49-a628-ba9211dc7aae-0005787e") in the views list but obviously it isn't there. So what is the meaning of that field. I tried to use it while invoking the [GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) endpoint but it's returning a 404 error... all in all a set of very frustrating and confusing API's.

Comment: you are in the right direction to get metadata of 2d view from  pushpin issue. The only trick is sheet_metadata.sheetGuid is viewerable Id of the view/sheet. It is not metadata id. metadata id is that of the physical data (3d is svf, svf2, 2d is pdf in this case). so you would map the id of GET:metadata with that of sheet_metadata.sheetGuid by the data from Manifest

Comment: but, it sounds your problem is no any metadata ids for those sheets at all, if GET:metadata. I did an experiment just now by uploading a new Revit model (with 2D sheets), it looks all working well. metadata ids of all sheets are available. I am wondering: does this id exist in GET:manifest?  Please feel free to email me to setup a call meeting

Comment: Thanks for quick turnover mate, it's been 2 months I asked the question and in between it's been submitted through direct channel and submitted to BIM360 team who actually had to fix the bug. So as you test now it's been fixed. Thanks for the extra info, I'll get back to you if I cannot find my way from the sheetGuid. This would deserve a bit more documentation or blogging IMO. Thanks